# Why does changing dispatcher in catch block throw VerifyError

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, verifyerror

I want to understand why this exception is thrown when I use `withContext()` with `Dispatchers.Main` or `Dispatchers.IO` in catch block.

Here's my code:

```
init {

    viewModelScope.launch {
        try {
            throw RuntimeException("whatever")
        } catch (e: Exception){
            withContext(Dispatchers.MAIN) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code throws `java.lang.VerifyError`

```
Verifier rejected class xx.xxxx.ErrorViewModel: java.lang.Object 
    xx.xxxx.ErrorViewModel$1.invokeSuspend(java.lang.Object) 
  failed to verify: java.lang.Object
    xx.xxxx.ErrorViewModel$1.invokeSuspend(java.lang.Object): 
      [0x3D] register v4 has type Reference: java.lang.Exception but expected 
      Precise Reference: kotlin.jvm.internal.Ref$ObjectRef 
      (declaration of 'xx.xxxx.ErrorViewModel$1' appears in 
      /data/app/xx.xxxx-9pkI5L5NB9qa1CWUxAapUw==/base.apk!classes2.dex)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should never see a VerifyError; this probably indicates a bug in the compiler.

I'd suggest raising an issue on the JetBrains [YouTrack](https://kotl.in/issue) site.

Comment: I reported it, thanks. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-43550